# Bootstrap Navbar with a side bar when viewed in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using Bootstrap Navbar for my web application and it works fine.
Using this [LINK](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

It is also responsive and that what I need but as you know the bootstrap navbar changes to hamburger icon when screen size reduces and changes to a drop down.

Something like this [image]

Where as I want to create a side navbar, by side nav I mean it should display elements like in materialize CSS [LINK](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html)

[image]

I did a lot of research and got this https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

But here there is not navbar up top it's just a side navbar where as I want this feature when the screen size reduces to mobile.

Also, my bootstrap navbar menu has drop downs so I don't know how to handle that in side nav CSS. Please help I am a novice in CSS.

I cannot go for materialize CSS as the cost of making all the bootstrap changes to materialize is way to much.

And if this is possible using plain CSS it's like icing on cake.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

here is my nav bar

```
nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded  navbar-fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="isActive = !isActive">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a routerLink="/home"><img src="angular.png" class = "myImage" alt="Image"/></a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown" [ngClass]="{show : isActive}">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" appDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Basic Concepts
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a [routerLink]="['/a4']" class="dropdown-item">Angular Component</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['/cli']" class="dropdown-item">Angular CLI</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['/inout']" class="dropdown-item">Event Emitters</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/template']">Template Driven Forms</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/reactive']">Reactive Forms</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/directives']">Angular Custom Directives</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/pipes']">Custom Pipes</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/viewchild']">View Child</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/view']">View Encapsulation</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" appDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Advanced Concepts
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/ngrx']">Angular Redux using ngrx/store</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/guard']">Angular Guards</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/host']">Host & Host-Context</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/dynamic']">Dynamic Component</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" appDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Additional
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink2">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/charts']">Angular + HighCharts</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/firebase']">FireBase Functions</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/myworks']">My Angular Projects</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/comment']">Comments</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/faq']"><strong>F.A.Q</strong></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="openDialog()">Contact Card</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you may try using a Javascript library for this.
Or in bootstrap, this link might help you. [Check out here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/bootstrap-3-slide-in-menu-navbar-on-mobile)

Comment: @JaysonJohn i am trying to have a navbar when the page is viewed in browswer and when the page resizses the nabvar whould become a side navbar which is collapsible like the menu on bootstrap navbar instead of srop down it should be a side navabr

Answer (score 5):

If am not wrong, you want to achieve "sliding menu" for mobile using bootstrap. Here is a snippet you can use to achieve the purpose:

Reference link: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-lateral-slide-menu

**Example HTML:**

```
<header role="banner" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" data-target-2=".side-collapse-container" type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-inverse side-collapse in">
          <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#users">Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://placesforlove.com">Places</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container side-collapse-container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>This is a side opening nav demonstration</p>
        <p>Make your browser smaller and the top menu wil become into a lateral slider menu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
          padding-top: 50px;
          position: relative;
      }

      pre {
          tab-size: 8;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          .side-collapse-container{
              width:100%;
              position:relative;
              left:0;
              transition:left .4s;
          }
          .side-collapse-container.out{
              left:200px;
          }
          .side-collapse {
              top:50px;
              bottom:0;
              left:0;
              width:200px;
              position:fixed;
              overflow:hidden;
              transition:width .4s;
          }
          .side-collapse.in {
              width:0;
          }
      }
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
            var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
            var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
            var sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');
            sideslider.click(function(event){
                $(sel).toggleClass('in');
                $(sel2).toggleClass('out');
            });
        });
```

Comment: will it work with bootstrap ? it wont override any other settings right ? and will it handle any drop downs if any on the navbar ?, beacuse in the link the navbar has just one property but if it has like a dropdown will that work out

Comment: Yes, it should work as expected with bootstrap,
Give it a try then comment here if you face problems.

Dont forget to add all necessary js/css files please.

Comment: it dosent work in my case the whole app behavies wierd can you check  updated my navbar.I wanted to accept the answer but it doesnt work in my case i am using nav where as it is div in your case please help

Answer (score 1):

Pls. see

> https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/fk63zzbz/3/

I see on above comment

HTML

```
<!-- Navigation -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo_white.png" class="logo" alt="logo"/>
                  </div>
              </a>

          </div>

              <div class="navbar-collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>

      </div>
      <!-- End Navigation-->
```

CSS

```
.indexcity {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.right {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-collapse{
      background-color:#ffc107;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      transition:all 0.8s ease-out;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left: 700px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #000;
    }
}
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass('right');
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('indexcity');
    });
});
```

Comment: Will it handle the dropdown in navbar if it has any like if we have a menu on the navbar ?

Comment: Tested it. It will

Comment: it dosent work in my case the whole app behavies wierd can you check  updated my navbar . I wanted to accept the answer but it doesnt work in my case i am using nav where as it is div in your case please help

Comment: I have posted the whole Nav element on the question it uses bootstrap v4 Please help